# iOS Edit push notification message

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to  edit push notification messages that are shown in notification centre of iPhone from client side?

Comment: By "edit" do you mean "change without closing the actual notification and loading the new one"? Or literally edit (some inline-editing interface)?

Comment: Actually my notification message shown in top list contain one date part , i want to convert it from utc to local format at the time when shown it in phone

Comment: reffer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from